# Adding validation in fb pixel code onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I have a pixel code that submit a report in a submit button form and how can I add some validation to prevent the code from firing if the form fields are empty?

Here's the code

```
<input onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Leaderboard Challenge', 'Submit - Step 3'); fbq('track', '<LEADERBOARD_COMPETITION>');" class="main-button f-right" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn">
```

Comment: Update its `onClick` attr and add custom function in it. Then on valid, call those functions. Or add required attribute to those fields

Comment: I will change the onClick to onSubmit? attr?

Comment: Please try first with required attr. If that fails then you will have to do things manually.

Comment: Can you check my code if that is correct? `function onButtonClick() {
   $('#cForm').on('submit', function(){
       if($(this).valid()) {
     fbq('track', '<LEADERBOARD_COMPETITION>');
     ga('send', 'event', 'Leaderboard Challenge', 'Submit - Step 3');
    } else {
     return false;
    }
   });
 }`